# jQuery divide a variable

Tags: jquery, css, math, margin, jsfiddle

Why won't this work?  Tearing my hear out... 
This fiddle has been updated with the approved answer
http://jsfiddle.net/jbreezy/pswdn2wb/ 
`$(document).ready(function() {
    var marginFix = $('.marginFix').css('font-size');
    var onethirdMargin = parseInt(marginFix / 3);
    $('.marginFix').css({"margin-top":marginFix});
    $('.marginFix').css({"margin-bottom":onethirdMargin});
});`

As you can see there, I just want the variable 'onethirdMargin' to be 1/3 of the other variable.  
So essentially no matter what you ever set the font-size to in the css, that elements margin-top will equal to said font-size, and the margin-bottom will be 1/3 of that automatically (If you apply the class marginFix to it).  Currently the margin-bottom is still just staying equal as well...  Any help is super appreciated!

Comment: `marginFix` is given with its units (as in 24px) so you cannot user `parseInt(...)` with it w/o removing the units first.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

change

```
var onethirdMargin = parseInt(marginFix / 3);
```

to

```
var onethirdMargin = parseInt(marginFix, 10) / 3;
```

If you parseint on "24px" it makes it the integer 24, then you can divide by 3.

According to Mozilla, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt you should always specify the 2nd parameter to ParseInt, the 10, it's the base you want to parse into. Thanks to Rocket Hazmat for the clarification on that.

Comment: You should be passing `10` as the 2nd parameter to `parseInt`.

Comment: Sure thing. :-) If you want to learn some debugging tips, try console.log()'ing your variables, you can see quickly that marginFix was 24px.